# Recursive function to convert a string containing math to integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

If I have a string `4+6*7/2` I want a function which calculates the value, in this case 25.
To achieve this I have written a recursive function which analyses the string character by character.

The basic algorithm goes (or should go) like this:
If the character we analyse now is a normal cipher and we haven't encountered an operator (+, -, *, /) yet we store it in a string called `first_nr`, which will eventually become the number on the left side of the operator. This we do until we encounter an operator. If we encounter an operator we store which operator it was so we know what to do later. Because we have encountered an operator, we now have to add the following numbers to another string called `second_nr` which will eventually become the number on the right-side of the operator. [I have implemented until here] Of course we also need to take the order of calculations in consideration, so I'd first ignore all the plusses and mins until all the times and divides are analyzed.

This way if I have for example the following action string:
`123+789+4`. My function would first put `123` in `first_nr`, then see an operator and store the `+` in `operator`. Because `operator != NULL` now it adds the following numbers, being `789` to `second_str`. Combining those three parameters we could form `first_nr + operator + second_str` in this case `123+789`. My program needs to execute that before it encounters the next operator so it will form in this case `912+4` and the recursion repeats.

I did an effort but it still has a lot of holes in it. For now I would be happy if I could get the string `12+5` running. So ignore all operators besides plus, ignore the order of calculations (first times and divide, than plus and min), and ignore multiple operators in one string.

If I can get the most basic string running I'll improve my algorithm to also work with more complex strings.

My effort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

//Enumeration of all the possible
//math operators
enum Operator {
    PLUS,
    MIN,
    TIMES,
    DIVIDE,
    UNDEFINED
};




/************************IGNORE********************/
Operator charToOperator(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case '+':
            return Operator::PLUS;
            break;
        case '-':
            return Operator::MIN;
            break;
        case '*':
            return Operator::TIMES;
            break;
        case '/':
            return Operator::DIVIDE;
            break;
        default:
            return Operator::UNDEFINED;
            break;
    }
}
/***************************************************/

/*
 * Recursive function performing all the calculations from an action string.
 * For example, if the string actions has value "5+7" in the first recursive run
 * result should contain 12 after the last recursion.
 *
 * :param result: Double containing the calculated result after the last recursion
 * :param actions: Action string (what you type in your calculator; e.g: 5+5). We analyze the first character of this string each time and add it to first_nr, second_nr, or make it the operator. First character gets deleted after each recursion
 * :param first_nr: Empty at first recursion, number of left side of the operator. So in 55+77 this paramater will be "55". Gets resetted at the next operator
 * :param second_nr: Idem as first_nr but for the right side of the operator.
 * :param oper: Operation to calculate the first_nr and second_nr
 */
int calculate(double& result, std::string& actions, std::string& first_nr, std::string& second_nr, Operator& oper) {
    //Base-condition:
    //If action string is empty return 
    if (actions == "") {
       return result;
    }

    //Get first character from action string
    char c = actions[0];

    //If first character is an operator
    char operatorInChar[] = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    if (std::find(std::begin(operatorInChar), std::end(operatorInChar), c) != std::end(operatorInChar)) {
        //If operator is not yet set in a previous recursion
        if (oper == NULL || oper == Operator::UNDEFINED) {
            oper = charToOperator(c);

            //If second_nr is not empty, we need to calculate the two numbers together
            if (second_nr != "") {
                //Update result
                result = std::stod(first_nr) + std::stod(second_nr); //For now we only implement plus

                //Calculation is done, so reset first_nr, second_nr and operator
                //for the next 'first_nr [operator] second_nr' block in the action string
                first_nr = "";
                second_nr = "";
                oper = Operator::UNDEFINED;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //If the character is not a operator but a number we append it to the correct nr
        //we add to first_nr if the operator is not yet set, if we already encountered an operator
        //we add to second_nr.
        //e.g: actions = "123+789"

        if (oper == NULL || oper == Operator::UNDEFINED) {
            first_nr += c;
        } else {
            second_nr += c;
        }

    }

    //Remove first character from action string because it's analysed in this recursion
    actions = actions.erase(0, 1);

    //Make recursive call
    return calculate(result, actions, first_nr, second_nr, oper);
}

int main() {
    //String we want to calculate
    std::string str = "5+7";
    std::string str_copy_for_output = str;

    //Variables
    double result = 0;
    std::string first_nr = "";
    std::string second_nr = "";
    Operator oper = Operator::UNDEFINED;

    //Call function
    int calculation = calculate(result, str, first_nr, second_nr, oper);

    //Output
    std::cout << str_copy_for_output << " = " << calculation << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the `result` is always 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `actions = actions.erase(0, actions.size());` this clears the entire string, isn't it?

Comment: @O'Niel Could you explain how this expression  4+6*7/2 gives  23?

Comment: You might also want to look into recursive descent parsers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 25. Lol sorry. Late night for me.

Comment: @user3365922 True, edited it in my code. Same issue remains though.

Comment: @Eraklon Thanks for the heads-up! Seems very relevant for my issue and will look that up for sure! If my code can't be fixed I'll use that. But I was hoping my own algorithm could be fixed/improved somehow.

Comment: You need three or four functions to do this properly. Do a search for 'recursive descent expression parser'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step through the program (with a debugger, `printf`s here and there, or mentally at least). Several interesting points, in order:

1. oper is UNDEFINED (it can’t be NULL btw as it’s not a pointer; a compiler could warn you), first_nr is "", second_nr is "", actions is "5+7".
2. `first_nr += c;` is executed.
3. oper is UNDEFINED, first_nr is "5", second_nr is "", action is "+7".
4. `oper = charToOperator(c);` is executed.
5. oper is PLUS, first_nr is "5", second_nr is "", action is "7".

Whoops! "+" is not in `actions` anymore, so `actions[0]` will never be found in `operatorInChar` and that branch will not be executed anymore. You probably need to additionally execute it at end of string.

Comment: Yeah I have done and tried that already. I know how to debug, hence why I found out there is something wrong with my algorithm. I'm asking for small but clear suggestions on how to fix my algorithm. Could you elaborate on this "ou probably need to additionally execute it at end of string"?

Comment: @O'Niel When your algorithm reaches the point where `actions == ""`, it needs to process the data queued, namely `nr_first`, `operator` and `nr_second` (if present, as in your example), the same way it does after reading any operator except of the first one.

Comment: I placed the code inside ```if (second_nr != "")``` on line 77 to ```if (action == "")``` on line 54. And got this error: ```terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stod: no conversion```

Comment: Debug your program. Do it. Inspect the values, step by step. And note that NULL is a literal 0 on many systems (including yours, as your program wouldn’t compile otherwise), and `Operator::PLUS` is equal to 0 as well (as the first enumerator), thus equal to NULL. That’s definitely not what you wanted. Consider using a `enum class` to prevent such mistakes.

Comment: The problem was indeed in comparing the enum with NULL. Now it works for ```5+7```. Answer accepted! Thanks!